# Determining if a function is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, uniform-convergence

$$f(x)= \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{(n+x)^2}$$ for $x \in [0, \infty)$

This above is a function which (with help) I have proved to be continuous on $[0, \infty)$

I now want to prove that $f$ is differentiable however I am struggling to see how.

I know that since $f$ is continuous, if is integrable which also applies to $f'$?

Furthermore the solution to this question posted ([Uniform convergence of $f'$ on an interval implies locally uniform convergence of $f$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2716557/uniform-convergence-of-f-on-an-interval-implies-locally-uniform-convergence-o)) is clearly a related answer as I know that proving differentiability involves the uniform convergence of a sequence of functions.

Can anyone explain to me how the example I linked might be applied to my particular problem?

Many thanks!

Comment: $\sum_{n\geqslant 1} \frac{2}{(n+x)^3}$ is uniformly convergent by the M-test. The series for $f(x)$ is termwise differentiable.

Comment: Note that $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac1{(n+x)^2}\right)=-\frac{2}{(n+x)^3}$ and$$\frac2{(n+x)^3}\le \frac1{n^3}$$

Comment: @RRL or Mark Is it possible for either of you to expand further on these results and how they might lead to an answer? This is something which I struggle with as well!

Comment: @JacquesWebster: The relevant theorem on switching derivative and infinite sum is discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2364089/148510).

Comment: So this result suggests that $f'(x)$ is uniformly convergent, I'm starting to understand that now but how do I apply that result to prove that $f$ is differentiable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we will be using following theorem

> Let $f_n → f$ pointwise on the closed interval $[a, b]$, and assume that
>   each $f_n$ is differentiable. If $(f'_n)$ converges uniformly on [a, b]
>   to a function $g$, then the *function f is differentiable* and $f' = g.$

First note that $f_{n}(x)$ is differentiable $$f_n'(x) = \frac{-2}{(n+x)^3}$$

now we have to show that $f_{n}'(x)$ uniformly  converges.we will use following theorem

> For each $n \in N$, let $f_n$ be a function defined on a set $A\subset R$, and
>   let $M_n > 0$ be a real number satisfying $|f_n (x)| ≤ M_n$  for
>   all $x \in A$. If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} M_n$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n$ converges uniformly on
>   A.

since $$|f_{n}'(x)| \leq \frac{2}{n^3} , \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{n^3} <\infty$$

we have and uniform converges and hence $f$ is differentiable on every closed interval $[a,b] , a\geq0, b \geq 0$ and hence differentiable on $[0, \infty)$